# How to find minimum value in an array created in other function?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a program which I display the array from input numbers by clicking the button "Add"(which have function "Push"). Then I created another button "What is minimum?" to find the minimum numbers among those and display it by function " Findmin"
But when I console it in Google it had the error **Minimum is not defined**
How can I access the array created in the function "Push" and use in function " Findmin"  ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Find Minimum Number</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <div>
     <h3><b>Find Minimum Number</b></h3>
   </div>
  Number add to Array:<input type="text" id="num" name="inputNumber">
  <button onclick="Push()">Add</button>
  <br>Array Number is:&nbsp<span id="result"></span>
  <br><button onclick="Findmin()">What is minimum?</button>
  <span id="Min"></span>
   <script>
    const array = [];
    const Min = document.querySelector("#Min");
    function Push()
    {
      let x = document.querySelector("#result");
      array.push(document.querySelector("#num").value);
      x.textContent = `[`+array+`]`;
    }
    function Findmin(array)
    {
        let minimum = array[0];
        for (let i =0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(minimum > array[i]) minimum = array[i];
        }
        return minimum
      Min.textContent = minimum;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit** : I changed the arg passed in **Findmin()** to "array" . Now I have the error **Cannot read property '0' of undefined** at this code **let minimum = array[0];** I still think the problem it is I don't know how to access in the array created in the first function not the const array = []

**Edit2** After all I think I have found my solution . My code work very well even if I input 2 same numbers to the array. For example : I input 34,34,567,9 then the result will return 9. I will post my changed code here. If anyone have any idea on how to make my code easier to read then you're very welcome!

```
 function Findmin()
    {
     let minimum = document.querySelector("#num").value[0];
     for (let i =0; i<document.querySelector("#num").value.length; i++)
        {
          if(minimum >= document.querySelector("#num").value[i]) 
          minimum = document.querySelector("#num").value[i];
        }
        Min.textContent = minimum;
```

Comment: isn't it an "fake" argument? I mean its name not necessary to match the real argument's name

Answer (score 1):

You return `minimum` before setting `Min`'s `textContent` to `minimum`. Returning exits the function - further code is not executed.

Instead, set the `textContent` before returning:

```js
const array = [];
const Min = document.querySelector("#Min");

function Push() {
  let x = document.querySelector("#result");
  array.push(document.querySelector("#num").value);
  x.textContent = `[` + array + `]`;
}

function Findmin(arr) {
  let minimum = array[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (minimum > array[i]) minimum = array[i];
  }
  Min.textContent = minimum;
  return minimum
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Find Minimum Number</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h3><b>Find Minimum Number</b></h3>
  </div>
  Number add to Array:<input type="text" id="num" name="inputNumber">
  <button onclick="Push()">Add</button>
  <br>Array Number is:&nbsp<span id="result"></span>
  <br><button onclick="Findmin()">What is minimum?</button>
  <span id="Min"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be a easier approch

```js
const array = [];
const Min = document.querySelector("#Min");

function Push() {
  let x = document.querySelector("#result");
  array.push(document.querySelector("#num").value);
  x.textContent = `[` + array + `]`;
}

function Findmin() {
  Min.textContent = Math.min(...array.map(Number));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3><b>Find Minimum Number</b></h3>
</div>
Number add to Array:
<input type="text" id="num" name="inputNumber" />
<button onclick="Push()">Add</button>
<br /> Array Number is:&nbsp
<span id="result"></span>
<br />
<button onclick="Findmin()">What is minimum?</button>
<span id="Min"></span>
```

Comment: You should probably add a comment as to what that `Math.max` statement does.

Answer (score 0):

you did it very will actually
but your problem is that you `return minimum` before   `Min.textContent = minimum`

another good way is to use `sort` the select first index `0`

```js
    const array = [];
    const Min = document.querySelector("#Min");
    function Push()
    {
      let x = document.querySelector("#result");
      array.push(document.querySelector("#num").value);
      x.textContent = `[`+array+`]`;
    }
    function Findmin(arr)
    {
        let minimum =  (array.sort((a, b) => a - b))[0];
               
        Min.textContent = minimum;

        return minimum
    }
```

```html
   <div>
     <h3><b>Find Minimum Number</b></h3>
   </div>
  Number add to Array:<input type="text" id="num" name="inputNumber">
  <button onclick="Push()">Add</button>
  <br>Array Number is:&nbsp<span id="result"></span>
  <br><button onclick="Findmin()">What is minimum?</button>
  <span id="Min"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Findmin(arr)
    {
      Min.textContent = Math.min(...arr);
    }
```

For more information =>
https://medium.com/@vladbezden/how-to-get-min-or-max-of-an-array-in-javascript-1c264ec6e1aa